# Simple Phase Diagram Question for a Simple system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Say I have the following system:

$$
y'_1 = -2y_1 + 2
$$
$$
y'_2 = -3y_2 + 6
$$

The solutions being
$$
y_1 = C_1e^{-2t}+1
$$
$$
y_2 = C_2e^{-3t}+2
$$

So for the phase diagram I plot a $y'_1$ and a $y'_2$ axises. Now the $y_1$ isocline is equal to 1. Now if I differentiate with respect to $y_1$ and sub in say 0.5 for t for left of the isocline and 2 for t for right of the isocline I get a negative answer for each. The book says to the right $y'_1$ it is negative and the left $y_1'$ is positive. What simple mistake am I making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your eigenvalues are negative.

What is that telling you about the critical point?

What happens to each of your solutions as $t$ increases (both of solutions are negative exponentials, so as $t$ increases, where does their limit end up)?

See the phase portrait below and look at the critical point and think about the items above. The green are the direction fields and the blue are different solution curves for different starting points.

Also, do you see why the books solution makes sense in this regard?

Lets look at $y'_1 = -2y_1 + 2$. This is the derivative. What happens when $y_1 = 1$? What happens for values of $y_1$ that are on the right (that is, they are greater than 1 in the right). What is the value of $y_1'$ from this equation (is it positive or negative)?

Also, what happens to the value of $y_1'$ for negative values of $y_1$? Where is the critical point.

Does that help?

[image]

Comment: Well I know my eigenvalues are -2 and -3. I don't remember to be honest what this is telling me about my critical points. I can see that both solutions converge to zero, but I want to be able to do it with the method in the book, so I have no trouble drawing phase diagrams. I don't see why the book's solution makes sense yet.

Comment: See: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/critical.html for both real, negative. Also, see [*Example 5*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealEigenvalues.aspx) Regards

Comment: @RulesOfTheGame: Please see my update and see if it helps.

Comment: Yep, completely. I was trying to take the derivative and I was reading the links you sent me. It has made it very clear and so much easier! Thank you.

Comment: @RulesOfTheGame: The MSE Community loves to help and we are happy to help! Regards

Comment: Your approaches are always full of pictures. like me. +1

Comment: @BabakS.: Pictures always make math so much more accessible to users, so when I can do them, I am all over it! Thanks and good to see you again my friend!

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you kindly! I hope the explanation set him on a better path and seeing pictures is worth tons! Regards

Comment: Yes, indeed!  We can "see" things in this day and age that could only be imagined year ago.